# On the sequence $(f_n)$ defined by $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=x^{f_n(x)}$

Tags: analysis, power-towers

Consider the numbers $x^x$,$x^{(x^x)}$,$x^{(x^{(x^x)})}$, etc.

Let $n$ be the number of times $x$ appears in the power tower and $f_n$ the
corresponding function, for example $f_4(x)=x^{(x^{(x^x)})}$.

a. It seems that the function $f_n$ has a (probably global) minimum inside the interval $[0,1]$ if and only if $n$ is even. Can this be proven?

b. What can be said about the value of $$I_n=\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx?$$
It seems that the sequence $(I_{2n})$
decreases and the sequence $(I_{2n-1})$ increases.

c. Finally, what about the limit of $I_n$ when $n\to\infty$?
Does it exist, and can its value be given exactly or only by numerical calculation?

Comment: Since all the $f(n)$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ they will all have a maximum and minimum.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Probably, the OP asks about _global_ minima on $(-\infty, \infty)$ located inside $[0,1]$...
Also, please add [tag:power-towers]

Comment: @AlexR Yes, that seems more likely.  I have added power towers.

Comment: Sometimes we denote $f(n)$ as $^n x$.

Comment: I mean a local minimum in the interval [0,1] (derivation is zero). For example, x^x has a (global) minimum at 1/e. For even n, this local minimum seems to be global, but to prove this seems difficult.

Comment: @Peter Hint: Use $\$\text{x^x}\$$ to get $x^x$ ;-)

Comment: Just to clarify, we're talking about things like $x^{(x^x)}$ as opposed to $(x^x)^x$

Comment: No, we're actually talking about things like $(x^x)^x$

Comment: @bluesh34 We are not. Why are you pretending we are?

Comment: lol. got confused, or did I?

Comment: Is it just me, or does no one notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ doesn't exist for $x<e^{-e}$?